# What's proper syntax for #each helper?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

So it seems Ember creates a controller (as I didn't specify one) and sets the model property defined in the route as a controller property.

Why is it that some of the other ways to loop through data that worked in previous versions simply don't output the data as show below?  Am I missing a dependency or have these methods simply been removed?

//this works

```
<ul class="list-unstyled">
  {{#each post in model}}
  <li>
    {{post.title}}
  </li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

//block params doesn't work

```
<h2>Posts</h2>

<ul class="list-unstyled">
  {{ log posts }}
  {{#each posts as |post|}}
  <li>
    {{post.title}}
  </li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

//neither does this

```
<ul class="list-unstyled">
  {{#each}}
  <li>
    {{title}}
  </li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

//http-mock for api endpoint

```
res.send({
  'posts': [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: "Bananas"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: 'Apples'
    }
  ]
});
```

//routes/posts.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('post');
  }
});
```

//package.json

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "broccoli-asset-rev": "^2.0.2",
    "ember-cli": "0.2.7",
    "ember-cli-app-version": "0.3.3",
    "ember-cli-babel": "^5.0.0",
    "ember-cli-content-security-policy": "0.4.0",
    "ember-cli-dependency-checker": "^1.0.0",
    "ember-cli-htmlbars": "0.7.6",
    "ember-cli-ic-ajax": "0.1.1",
    "ember-cli-inject-live-reload": "^1.3.0",
    "ember-cli-qunit": "0.3.13",
    "ember-cli-uglify": "^1.0.1",
    "ember-data": "1.0.0-beta.18",
    "ember-disable-proxy-controllers": "^1.0.0",
    "ember-export-application-global": "^1.0.2",
    "express": "^4.12.4",
    "glob": "^4.5.3",
    "morgan": "^1.5.3"
  }
```

//bower

```
{
  "name": "blog",
  "dependencies": {
    "ember": "1.12.0",
    "ember-cli-shims": "ember-cli/ember-cli-shims#0.0.3",
    "ember-cli-test-loader": "ember-cli-test-loader#0.1.3",
    "ember-data": "1.0.0-beta.18",
    "ember-load-initializers": "ember-cli/ember-load-initializers#0.1.4",
    "ember-qunit": "0.3.3",
    "ember-qunit-notifications": "0.0.7",
    "ember-resolver": "~0.1.15",
    "jquery": "^1.11.1",
    "loader.js": "ember-cli/loader.js#3.2.0",
    "qunit": "~1.17.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "~3.3.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: You're going to need to edit this and ask a specific question.

Answer (score 1):

You are right that Ember creates posts controller (of Ember.Controller class) and sets the model property as posts router model promise resolved.

the right way:

```
{{#each model as |post|}}
   {{post.title}}
{{/each}}
```

comments on other ways:

`{{#each post in model}} {{post.title}} {{/each}}` works too but this syntax is outdated, will be deprecated on Ember 2.0 road

`{{#each}} {{title}} {{/each}}` - deprecated `each` without block param, `title` here is a property of posts controller, so wasn't set.

`{#each posts as |post|}} {{post.title}} {{/each}}` syntax is ok, but posts property wasn't set in posts controller

Deprecations links:

http://emberjs.com/deprecations/v1.x/#toc_more-consistent-handlebars-scope

http://emberjs.com/deprecations/v1.x/#toc_code-in-code-syntax-for-code-each-code

http://emberjs.com/deprecations/v1.x/#toc_objectcontroller